# Find $(\sin x)^7$, reduced in specific terms

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

$(\sin x)^7 = a\sin 7x+b\sin 5x+c\sin 3x+d\sin x$. Find $d$. $x$ is an angle, and $a, b, c, d$ are all constants.

I am not sure where to start! The only idea I have is to possibly break up $(\sin x)^7$ into smaller parts such as $(\sin x)^2 * (\sin x)^2 * (\sin x)^3$.

Hints only, please.

Comment: Are you allowed to use complex numbers?  That's probably the easiest way.

Comment: @David: Sure. How would you suggest I use complex numbers, then?

Comment: @MathyPerson use $\sin^7(x) = \left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^7$. It'll be some hairy algebra but it'll work.

Comment: You can also write $\sin 3x$ as a polynomial in $\cos x$ and $\sin x.$ Then do the same for $\sin 5x.$ Then $\sin 7x.$ Add them up, fiddle with $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1,$ and there you go.

Comment: @WillJagy: I have currently: $$15 \sin x - 80 \sin^3 x +128 \sin^5 x -\sin^7 x$$ What next?

Comment: If that is your expression for $\sin 7x,$ then you need a separate expression for $\sin 5x$ and one for $\sin 3x.$

Comment: @WillJagy: Those are my expressions for the sum of $\sin x, \sin(3x), \sin(5x), \sin(7x)$ after simplification.

Comment: You don't add them ahead of time, you get four separate expressions, $\sin x$ is just itself, then the three others I indicated. When I said add them up I meant that each one would need some replacement of $\cos^2 x$ by $1 - \sin^2 x.$

Comment: @WillJagy: The terms that I had for each individual one already had only $\sin$ in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**.  Using Euler's formula and related things,
$$\eqalign{
  (\sin x)^7
  &=\Bigl(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\Bigr)^7\cr
  &=\cdots\quad\langle\hbox{expand by binomial theorem}\rangle\cr
  &=\frac{1}{(2i)^7}(e^{7ix}-e^{-7ix}+\langle\hbox{more terms}\rangle)\cr
  &=-\frac{1}{64}\sin7x+\langle\hbox{more terms}\rangle\ .\cr}$$
See if you can do the rest.

Comment: OK, so now take $a=e^{ix}$ and $b=-e^{-ix}$.  The terms I have written down are the first and the last.  You will also need to work out the binomial coefficients from Pascal's triangle.  See how you go.

Comment: I collected the first and last terms together.  Can you see which other pairs you should put together?

Comment: Yes, and if you can then write each pair as a sine term, you are pretty much finished.  Don't forget that the whole thing has $1/(2i)^7$ out the front.

Comment: I think you made a mistake somewhere.  In any case no need to write $\cos+i\sin$, once you have e.g. $e^{5ix}-e^{-5ix}$ you should be able to write that immediately in terms of sine.  Hint: look back at the first line of the algebra.

Answer (score 1):

We do a much simpler problem, which can be a step in the solution of your problem. The key is the product to sum formula
$$\sin a\cos b=\frac{\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)}{2}.\tag{1}$$
We also use the double-angle formula
$$\sin^2 x=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}.\tag{2}$$

Now we do $(\sin x)^3$. This is $\frac{\sin x}{2}-\frac{\sin x\cos 2x}{2}$. Now formula (1) gives $\frac{\sin x}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\left(\sin(3x)+\sin(-x)\right)$, which 
simplifies to 
$$\frac{1}{4}\left(3\sin x-\sin(3x)\right).\tag{3}$$

For $(\sin x)^5$, multiply our expression by $\sin^2 x$, that is, the right-hand side of (2), and use sum to product again.

Then comes $(\sin x)^7$.

**Remark:** Complex numbers are the right thing to use. But the sketch above shows it can be done using standard trigonometric identities. However, these trigonometric identities hold "because" of the more natural fact that $\exp(w)\exp(z)=\exp(z+w)$.

Comment: I am not sure who to give the green check to, but I accept your answer as well. :)

Comment: As I commented more than once, the complex variable version is the "right' way to do it. I wanted to do it using trig identities in order to show the problem can be solved using "school" math.